# El scrollbar de una tabla no esta apareciendo y el que aparece es el de la pagina

Tags: html, tailwind

como dice el título, estoy tratando de generar un scrollbar a la tabla, pero no está funcionando, pero si se está generando un scroll, pero a nivel página y no quiero eso porque se me está rompiendo toda la página.

Mi idea es mantener todo dentro de la tabla y que no se rompa.

```
    <div id="contenedor-tabla" class="w-full h-[50%]">
        <div class="w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center">
            <table class="w-[98%] h-[98%] text-md bg-white shadow-md table-fixed">
                <tbody class="w-[80%] h-[90%] overflow-y">
                    <tr class="border-b">
                        <th class="text-left p-3 px-5">Servico Salud</th>
                        ...
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Columnas dinamicas con data cargada desde Vue -->
                    <tr v-for="data in data_tabla" :key="data.id" class="border-b hover:bg-orange-100 bg-gray-100 overflow-y">
                        <td class="p-3 px-5"><input type="text" class="bg-transparent">${data.fields.servicio_salud}
                        </td>
                        ...
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow#scrolling-if-needed) debes poner tu tabla en un div con la clase `overflow-x` y el ancho requerido a cada columna, luego agregar la clase `w-full` a las clases de la tabla.

```
<div class='overflow-x'>
        <table class='table-auto overflow-scroll w-full'>
            <thead>
                <tr class='bg-gray-100'>
                    <th class='w-20 px-4 py-2'>ID</th>
                    <th class='px-4 py-2'>Name</th>
                    <th class='px-4 py-2'>Email</th>
<!-- Resto de la tabla -->
```